# MySQL LIKE condition with multiple backslashes, extra \ at the end

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I just noticed, that if i have a value in the db field, e.g. **'\\\'**, and I want to find it using SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%xxxx%' (wildcards at both sides)
```

then not only i need to put 3 times '\\\\' into sql, but also one more backslash at the end.

So my SQL would be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\ \\\\\\\ \%'; -- (I put spaces only here, just for clarity)
```

But if I use `LIKE 'xxxx'`

then no need for that one extra backslash at the end (total 12 backslashes not 13)

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e1dad/1)

**Note:** this happens when using utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation (if default collation is used, everything works fine)

Comment: Please edit your question and include your entire SELECT statement. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis Done (don't know what this has to do with the question, anyway...)

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. For matching three backslashes, you need to specify 12 of them in the LIKE argument, not 13. If you specify 13 of them, then the last one will make the final `%` a literal character to match also at the end. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3df50/4)

Comment: @trincot try using utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation

Comment: Indeed, something strange is going on. I'll be interested to see if someone has a good explanation for this. I found that the first `%` actually triggers the behaviour. Also, if you use another escape character, the behaviour is back to normal ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8afe59/1))

Comment: Has there been an explanation found for this?  I have the same: an extra \ is needed when using collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: the collation bug with utf8mb4_unicode_ci seems fixed in Fixed in 8.0.18:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81990

Answer (score 0):

To make things a bit easier if you don't really need to use the backslash as an escape character you can disable it with

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
```

You can also disable the backslash-as-escape=character behavior by including `--sql-mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES"` on the command line when starting MySQL or by including `sql-mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES"` in your MySQL option file (`my.cnf` on *nix, `my.ini` on Windows).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4120/1)

Best of luck.

Comment: what do I lose by disabling backslash as an escape character? What I won't be able to do then?

Comment: if i remember correctly, and I'm reaching pretty far back, disabling the the backslashes as escape characters means that things like `" this text has \"some quote\" "` will not escape the quote within that text.

Comment: so basically I need backslash as escape character (if my db accepts any kind of string). What I have found as an alternative is to use db field as binary. That solves the issue